# SQL server: Get record with date closest to given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table `dbo.studies` with `datetime` `column studydate`

I want to query the database using the `datetime` variable `givendate` to find the record closest to the `datetime` in  `column studydate`

Using:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM studies
WHERE studies.studydate < givendate
ORDER BY studies.studydate DESC
```

Will result in the record that is **less and closest** to `givendate`, but I need the record **closest to** `givendate`, **regardless of whether it's less or more** then `studydate`

Any thoughts on how to find it?

Comment: Add an example of data input and output after query pls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 s.*
FROM studies s
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(day, s.studydate, @givendate));
```

This uses `DATEDIFF()` to get the closest date.  Note that this is using `day` for the difference.  If your "dates" have a time component, you might want a different date part.

Note that this will not take advantage of indexes.  A faster method (if you have the indexes) is a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT TOP (1) s.*
FROM ((SELECT TOP 1 s.*
       FROM studies s
       WHERE s.studydate <= @givendate
       ORDER BY s.studydate DESC
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP 1 s.*
       FROM studies s
       WHERE s.studydate > @givendate
       ORDER BY s.studydate ASC
      )
     ) s
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(day, s.studydate, @givendate);
```

Although this is more complicated, each subquery can use an index on `studydate`.  The final sort would have only two rows, so it should be really fast.

Comment: works! I'll be using more variables than just `givendate`, so your first option will work just fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use `datediff` function in order by it will always return the nearest 1

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM studies    
ORDER BY  DATEDIFF(dd,studies.studydate, givendate) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM studies
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(second, @givendate, studies.studydate))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's best to add a few words to explain how your code solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Order By ABS(DATEDIFF(day, YourDate, GetDate()))
```

**Is The Best Method For Get Distinct and unique Recod When Your Table is Many Row and one column different**

```
    SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnName ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(day, YourDate, GetDate()))) RowNumber
    FROM [tableName]
)A
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).